# A straightforward API to gain exp. w/ web services

Tags: android, api

Hey all. I need to work on all of the skills that come along with working with web services in Android. Most of the apps I've worked on have used static/local data. Obviously, to create something powerful, I need to learn how to work with web services.

To that end, does anyone have any recommendations for an easy API to work with? I don't really have any preference (I'm doing this project just so I can learn), though I'd rather not work with Twitter.

So, I'm looking for one of the popular APIs, but something that's relatively simple so that I don't have to be bogged down in an ultra-complex API. I want to be able to focus more on the Android/Java implementation.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many API that you can use to leverage your skills. Facebook is one of them but you can also have a look at websites such as Read It Later, Instapaper, Delicious or MeeGo that use simple web API with JSON/XML to transmit data.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to go with Facebook;

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

While many others might disagree, some maybe saying it isn't a web service at all, personally I liked the idea of having many different kinds of data. And chose to do some experiments on top of Facebook Graph API based on pretty much same rationale you're describing here.

It really doesn't take long while to make your first connection, namely have your application authorized, and after you have an access token, Graph API is rather intuitive to use. And Facebook SDK doesn't make it any harder either.

Anyway, that's my two cents, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: This sounds like a great suggestion, but I'm wondering if I might be overkill for me. I really need to be able to get the most simple things working, namely getting authorized and then getting data and parsing it. I'd prefer something that returns JSON data.

Comment: Graph API returns JSON data. And it really is rather easy to get familiar with, I'm saying this as a person who started his first Android project using Facebook Android SDK. With no previous experience on Android UI whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

First web API I used was Flickr. They have great documentation, most (all?) of the data can be returned in JSON format, and it's pretty expansive. I thought it was pretty simple to use, myself.